# How to handle girlfriends past / social media usage?

Tags: relationships

**Background**

My girlfriend (Filipina) is (like almost all Filipinos) an intensive user of social media. Means: Lot of activity and almost 3k "friends". It's okay. People are different and that's nothing to complain about.

Actually we are 6.5k miles apart. On December we will be together without any distance.

The lady is 24 (I'm 29). And of course, it's normal, that people have a past. I have a past, you have a past. So far so good.

Before we met each other she was a flirty type of girl. Means, she talked to a lot of guys, who also left some (flirty) comments (Different type of guys. Also elder guys). It was before me. So usually nothing that should bother me. But.

Maybe I'm different. I deleted all "traces" of my past. It is past for a reason. And I don't want her to feel bad. And I think that's my point. I know it was before me, but it's kinda killing me to see these comments. And to imagine how her life would be when we wouldn't have met each other. Yes, it sounds strange. And sometimes I try to give some "hints". I never told her directly that it's killing me.

I would never forbid her things. I don't have the right to do so and she's loyal. That's nothing I should worry about. I don't care about social media and I only use the messenger to text her.

It is just a strange feeling to see "so much past". I mean you almost "reconstruct" her entire life. And that's not only dangerous. It also gives me the feeling, that the past is not completely past. The "addiction" to collect (female) friends is one thing. (I can't understand it, but that's her thing :D)

**Question: How would you deal with that? Talking to her? More or less directly? Ignoring it?** I don't know if it's a kind of jealousy, but I don't like the feeling. Maybe I'm overreacting or too sensitive, that's why I'd like to hear other opinions.

I know. It's "just" social media. But actually it's a part of the relationship, it's our way to communicate. It will be over in a few months. Nevertheless it's something that affects my mood.

Comment: We can't really tell you what to do, we can only help you with how to do the thing you want to do properly. As such, this question is probably not one we can answer.

Comment: I think this is an incredibly good question that has the potential to be rephrased. Not VTC as a result. If you ask "how do I talk to her about this?" And take out the other questions it will be on topic.

Comment: This question feels very off topic here: too broad, opinion based, and not really answerable

Comment: @Stacey: If it has the potential to be a good question, but isn't an answerable one in its current form, that's precisely what voting to close is for. It's put on hold until it's edited to be answerable.

Comment: @V2Blast theoretically, yes, but unfortunately in practice that doesn't always happen. A new user will see their question is on hold and give up, and even if they do edit, people vote to open much less often than they vote to close.

Comment: @Stacey: In such cases, rather than not voting to close, people should still vote to (temporarily) close the question while it's refined - but at least some of those voting to close the question should also leave a comment welcoming the asker to the site (if new) and explaining why the question is unsuitable in its current state, and hopefully giving some suggestions to edit the question into a suitable form. At least, that's how I see it.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question

> I would never forbid her things. I don't have the right to do so and
>   she's loyal. That's nothing I should worry about. I don't care about
>   social media and I only use the messenger to text her.

Deal with your own insecurity instead of attempting to place any onus on another individual. No matter what the other person does or does not do, only you have control over your own emotions.

> Nevertheless it's something that affects my mood.

Be careful. The concept of mood being contagious is not foreign to eastern culture and philosophy. You could easily allow your own emotional insecurity to affect your

> girlfriend

"mood", which could be disastrous; as no woman, no matter their cultural heritage, actively seeks to be involved with an emotionally insecure man, except to dominate that man.

Get a hold of yourself.

If your "girlfriend" is truly "loyal" and you "don't care about social media" then you are alright.

If, on the other hand, you actually want to control the activities of another individual, you cannot escape the grief that you are creating for yourself, as that is a full time and highly volatile job; ask any pimp. Your issue does not sound like a problem a pimp would have, but rather, a trick. Don't be a trick. Or trick yourself into thinking you can control a grown woman. You can't.

> **Ignoring it?**

Yes. That is a reasonable decision to make. Before you drive yourself crazy with unwarranted jealously. You do not own your "girlfriend".